# Unable to see edit history of a question by tapping "edited x minutes ago" on Android

Tags: support, bug, android-app

On Android se app I am unable to view a post's edit history unless I opt to open the question in the browser.

Clicking on the edit field causes the box to flash light blue, but nothing happens.

Comment: Such feature simply does not exist, and too expansive (in developer hours) to add. No bug.

Comment: Wat, but the mobile site has it implemented already??

Comment: Site is very very different than app. Different coding, much bigger team of developers. There is only one developer working on the android app, and as far as I know, not even full time. (So only the most urgent bugs have any chance of being fixed, "nice to have" things are... well, doomed)